Geometry nodes : How to manage point distribution based on a material
I would like to know how to use a material (the pink volume in that case) to manage the distribution of the instances on points.
The pink volume :

From a previous question, i learned how to make my points only appear in the sphere :


Now, i'm searching for a way to control even more the distribution of the points by making them concentrated in the "tendrils" and avoid the empty spots.

Thanks in advance :)

Questions shouldn't rely solely on a .blend file attachment, please use some screenshots and text to describe your issue. Geonodes can only read material index, but not the result of the material, because material is computed after geonodes, typically on GPU (whereas geonodes are computed on CPU)

thank you for your comment, i've edited my post ;). If i can't use the output of my material, do you know an other way to obtain the result ?

You can use an output of your material, but for that you need to render an image, which is 2D, or an animation, where the frame number can be considered the 3rd dimension. Then you can analyze the image to read the material output (color) for each pixel. It's probably not going to lead you anywhere, however, and that's why XY problems are frowned upon. You never showed your material (again, .blend file should be a supplement, but the merit should be in the question).

Keep in mind the possible circular dependency: if the color of the point depends on it being occluded by other points or not, and the position/visibility of a point depends on the color, then both affect each-other. Of course maybe the problem is as simple as moving some logic from the shader to geonodes, so that you calculate the color within geonodes, then based on that spawn/position a point, and only then calculate the color again or use the color already calculated (and stored) in geonodes.
